# Do I need a many-to-many relationship for the leave approver of a company?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a: `User` and `Company`

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'projects.Company',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )


class Company(models.Model):
    '''Company model
    every user needs to be assigned to a company
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Now I need a to set a few `leave approvers` per `company` which will be `Users`. There can be a few and I want to set a priority for them.

If it were a single `LeaveApprover` then I would simply add a one-to-one to the `Company` model with a foreign key to `LeaveApprover`. But In my case A company can have many approvers, an approver can only approve a single company.

Do I need a `many-to-many` field?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a designation field in User model will work.
You can easily filter user based on designation ;  It will differentiate if he is employee or approver.
The model will look like this....

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'projects.Company',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )


class Company(models.Model):
    '''Company model
    every user needs to be assigned to a company
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Now company can have many approvers and an approver can only approve a single company.

In your views you can write logic or assign specific permissions based on role.